# TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER always null on Android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

On Android 9 the call:

```
String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Always return `null`, how can I fix this under **Android 9**? It works for my old releases.
How can I get the incoming number of a call, these days?

Comment: You are using broadcast receiver ryt ? In there `onIncomingCallStarted(contex..)` will be triggered twice.. the first time the number will be **null** and the **second time you will get it..**

Comment: On the second call it's also null.

Comment: You have the permissions ryt

Comment: can you publish it in google play store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need both `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `READ_CALL_LOG` permissions granted first, and then be ready for two broadcasts - one with no number as [documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED):

> If the receiving app has Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG and
>   Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission, it will receive the
>   broadcast twice; one with the EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER populated with the
>   phone number, and another with it blank.

Comment: Yes my was crashing and I found out that broadcast receiver executing two times. One with null number and one with number, so I had to handle that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }
          if (number != null && !number.isEmpty() && !number.equals("null")) {
                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
                Log.d("TEST :","NUMBER =>"+number);
                return; 
            }

        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},
            1);
}
```

Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```